# getting The command exited with code -532459699 while building from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tfsbuild

Following is the copy of log file

```
   Creating directory "obj\Release\".
PreBuildEvent:
C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Sources\IT\jsmin\jsmin.exe
cwd is 'C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Binaries'

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Binaries\Shared\Javascript\Model\CModel_uncompressed.js'.
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
 at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
 at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
 at System.IO.File.CreateText(String path)
 at JsMin.Program.Main(String[] args) in Z:\downloads\JsMinTest\JsMinTest\JsMinConsole\Program.cs:line 52
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(902,9): error MSB3073: The command "C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Sources\IT\jsmin\jsmin.exe" exited with code -532459699. [C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Sources\IT\IT.vbproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Sources\IT\IT.vbproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

I have checked the path jsmin.exe is on the path. but there is no shared directory being created by TFS as mentioned in the following link

```
C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Binaries\Shared\Javascript\Model\CModel_uncompressed.js.
```

Plz guide what I am missing.

Comment: So there is no `\Shared` under `C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Binaries`, right? Is your `CModel_uncompressed.js` placed elsewhere under `Binaries`?

Comment: Yes No \Shared dir. and also cant find that model under binaries as well.

Comment: FYI -532459699 = 0xE0434F4D, which is the COM structured exception code.

Comment: Well, just create the directory then.  A prebuild event should do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you have a `C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Sources\..\Model\*.js`.
You are then trying to minify this *.js, on the "C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Binaries..". That fails because the file is not available.
One way to go is to change the property of the *.js in VStudio. Right-click on it on the Solution Explorer, choose 'Properties' and set "Copy to Output Directory" into "Copy Always". This should deliver your files into the Binaries directory during TFS Build.
Another idea is to enforce the minifier directly in the `\Sources` directory (set cwd into `C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Sources\Shared`).
This latter seems more reasonable to me - still, beware, I haven't ever employed a minifier.

Comment: tried First option but still same result. As it is just not creating any shared folder under binaries and if I create it manually with next build its no longer there. Not sure about later as could not understand how to do.

Comment: How to set cwd into C:\Builds\2\box\IT\Sources\Shared

Comment: Right-click on the Solution Explorer on the *.csproj & select 'Properties' - then go to "Build Events". Can you please share what your current entry under "Pre-build event command line" is?

Comment: its $(ProjectDir)jsmin\jsmin.exe

Comment: Just that? Obviously $(ProjectDir) is resolved OK, but I'd expect some $(OutDir) markation pointing the tool (jsmin.exe) to its' targets (the *.js files). Maybe jsmin operates on a config-file?

Comment: just checked there is no config file. it is hard coded and fixed condition for shared/javascript files...Any idea how can I edit TFS to overwrite file at the same path instead of changing CWD

Comment: and output directory of project in compile option is set to \bin. Also tried to change it to binaries but same result